# Ubuntu 19.04 install does not reboot

Tags: system-installation, 19.04

The reboot stalls at :-
Starting GNOME Display Manager
Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Starting Hostname Service
Started OpenVPN service
Started Hostname service

Comment: Tried Ubuntu Budgie 19.04 and it worked OK!